# Non-cryptography algorithms to protect the data

Tags: cryptography

I was able to find a few, but I was wondering, is there more algorithms that based on data encoding/modification instead of complete encryption of it. Examples that I found:

1. Steganography. The method is based on hiding a message within a message;
2. Tokenization. Data is mapped in the tokenization server to a random token that represents the real data outside of the server;
3. Data perturbation. As far as I know it works mostly with databases. Adds noise to the sensitive records yet allows to read general and public fields, like sum of the records on a specific day.

Are there any other methods like this?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question, but maybe knowing about "[differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy)" could be relevant

Comment: @SamMason, your answer helps. If I understood the mechanism properly, it has some properties from randomization (adds noise) and generalization (gives general information while protecting individual records). 
P.s. I am not sure how to design my question better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to publish this data there are other methods similars to data perturbation, its called Data Anonymization [[source](https://www.imperva.com/learn/data-security/anonymization/)]:

> Data masking—hiding data with altered values. You can create a mirror
>   version of a database and apply modification techniques such as
>   character shuffling, encryption, and word or character substitution.
>   For example, you can replace a value character with a symbol such as
>   “*” or “x”. Data masking makes reverse engineering or detection
>   impossible.
>
> Pseudonymization—a data management and de-identification method that
>   replaces private identifiers with fake identifiers or pseudonyms, for
>   example replacing the identifier “John Smith” with “Mark Spencer”.
>   Pseudonymization preserves statistical accuracy and data integrity,
>   allowing the modified data to be used for training, development,
>   testing, and analytics while protecting data privacy.
>
> Generalization—deliberately removes some of the data to make it less
>   identifiable. Data can be modified into a set of ranges or a broad
>   area with appropriate boundaries. You can remove the house number in
>   an address, but make sure you don’t remove the road name. The purpose
>   is to eliminate some of the identifiers while retaining a measure of
>   data accuracy.
>
> Data swapping—also known as shuffling and permutation, a technique
>   used to rearrange the dataset attribute values so they don’t
>   correspond with the original records. Swapping attributes (columns)
>   that contain identifiers values such as date of birth, for example,
>   may have more impact on anonymization than membership type values.
>        Data perturbation—modifies the original dataset slightly by applying techniques that round numbers and add random noise. The range
>   of values needs to be in proportion to the perturbation. A small base
>   may lead to weak anonymization while a large base can reduce the
>   utility of the dataset. For example, you can use a base of 5 for
>   rounding values like age or house number because it’s proportional to
>   the original value. You can multiply a house number by 15 and the
>   value may retain its credence. However, using higher bases like 15 can
>   make the age values seem fake.
>
> Synthetic data—algorithmically manufactured information that has no
>   connection to real events. Synthetic data is used to create artificial
>   datasets instead of altering the original dataset or using it as is
>   and risking privacy and security. The process involves creating
>   statistical models based on patterns found in the original dataset.
>   You can use standard deviations, medians, linear regression or other
>   statistical techniques to generate the synthetic data.

Is this what are you looking for?

**EDIT:** added link to the source and quotation.

Comment: This is not a copy and paste site. At least give the reference. This is a verbatim copy of [Anonymization](https://www.imperva.com/learn/data-security/anonymization/) from Imperva